# All items are appearing in one position instead of different positions in a scrollview

Tags: cocos2d-x

Now i am implementing the scroll view in cocos2dx (2.2.6 c++), in that
 all the scroll view item is coming only one position. I want all the ietm with some specific padding so that i give the padding but then also its not working properly. My scrollview code is here below. In that i create array of `CCMenuItemImage` and add that in `CCMenu`. I also add `abc->alignItemsHorizontallyWithPadding(100)` then also padding is not consider so what are the changes in my code for this issue.

```
scrollview=cocos2d::extension::CCScrollView::create(CCSize(ccp(winsize.width/768*760, winsize.height/1024*550)),NULL);
// scrollview->setPosition(ccp(winsize.width/768*160,winsize.height/1024*1200));
scrollview->setPosition(ccp(winsize.width/768*0,winsize.height/1024*0));
scrollview->retain();
scrollview->setContentSize(CCSizeMake(slider->getContentSize().width+500,slider->getContentSize().height+250));
scrollview->setViewSize(ccp(winsize.width/768*724,winsize.height/1024*500));

scrollview->setContentOffset(ccp(winsize.width/768*350, winsize.height/1024*120));
scrollview->setDirection(cocos2d::extension::kCCScrollViewDirectionHorizontal);
scrollview->setContentOffsetInDuration(ccp(500,0), 0.5);

for (int i=1; i<10; i++) {
    CCString *str = CCString::createWithFormat("haircopy%d.png", i);
    flower_menuietm[i]=CCMenuItemImage::create(str->getCString(),NULL,this,menu_selector(HelloWorldScene::selectSprite));
    flower_menuietm[i]->setTag(i);
    //flower_menuietm[i]->setScale(0.9);

    abc=CCMenu::create(flower_menuietm[i],NULL);
    abc->alignItemsHorizontallyWithPadding(100);
    scrollview->addChild(abc);
}
this->addChild(scrollview);
```

Comment: please use the "Source Code" format (intent all code with addition 4 spaces)

Answer (score 1):

You problem is that you create a separate *CCMenu* for each *CCMenuItem*
To fix this, just create one *CCMenu* and add all *CCMenuItems* to it;

```
...

abc = CCMenu::create();
scrollview->addChild(abc);
for (int i=1; i<10; i++) {
    CCString *str = CCString::createWithFormat("haircopy%d.png", i);
    flower_menuietm[i]=CCMenuItemImage::create(str->getCString(),NULL,this,menu_selector(HelloWorldScene::selectSprite));

    flower_menuietm[i]->setTag(i);
    //flower_menuietm[i]->setScale(0.9);
    abc->addChild(flower_menuietm[i]);
}
abc->alignItemsHorizontallyWithPadding(100);

this->addChild(scrollview);
```

Comment: scrollview is not moving smoothly for that what to do??

Comment: try running your game on a device

Comment: still in In scroll view what is  the use of setcontentoffset and setContentSize  that i don't know.Please explain why it is use ???